# Spring - host that's generated by swagger is HTTP instead of HTTPS - set host manually

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I use Open Api:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is how the swagger ui looks like:

[image]

Is there some setting for it to generate a secure url?
how do I simply overwrite the base path all together (for example via `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

@Ray is right. But the domain is hidden.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74261128/20325718

[image]

If you also want to display the domain, you can try the following method.

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIDefinitionConfiguration {
  @Component
  @Profile("prd")
  @OpenAPIDefinition(servers = @Server(url = "https://example.com"))
  public static class PrdOpenAPIDefinitionConfiguration {
  }

  @Component
  @Profile("local")
  @OpenAPIDefinition(servers = @Server(url = "https://local.example.com"))
  public static class LocalOpenAPIDefinitionConfiguration {
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=prd
```

Or if you want to display all environments, you can also display it by the following method.

```java
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        servers = {
                @Server(
                        url = "https://{profile}.example.com/",
                        variables = {
                                @ServerVariable(
                                        name = "profile",
                                        allowableValues = { "prd", "local" },
                                        defaultValue = "prd"
                                )
                        }
                )
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem after updating an app. My solution was to add into my nginx config `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

Comment: I took the suggestion from here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/171 and https://gist.github.com/kuleszaj/1911050